# boost::scoped_lock RAII behaviour

Tags: c++, boost, scope, mutex, scoped-lock

From a *Container* class, I'd like to `lock` a vector of `boost::mutex`, each one owned by a *Controlled* instance (weird code design, but for MWE purpose only).

```
// std::vector<Controlled*> _vData;

void Container::main_method()
{
  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock my_lock(_vData.at(i)->_mutex);
    this->processing(i);
  }

  // precondition for post_processing(): all processing() calls done
  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock my_lock(_vData.at(i)->_mutex);
    this->post_processing(i);
  }
}
```

But since `processing` is cpu-bound and *Controlled* objects are modified from elsewhere in the mean time, I'd like to simply do a cycled `scoped_lock` at the beginning of the `main_method`, in order to lock **everything** and **asap**, such as

```
void Container::desired_main_method()
{
  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock my_lock(_vData.at(i)->_mutex);
  }

  // locks destroyed here, aren't they ?

  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    this->processing(i);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    this->post_processing(i);
  }
}
```

Problem is, if I understanded well the RAII idiom and the `scoped_lock` context, that in this way, the locks would go out of scope soon after the lock `for` cycle ends.

I've tried to `new` an array of locks at *Container* ctor and to `delete` it at its dtor, but I guess this is against the RAII idiom itself.

What did I misunderstand, or how could I refactor the whole issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your question is: *"how do I use a RAII-like scoped lock for multiple mutexes at the same time?"*

Then you can either create your own RAII-wrapper for multiple locks or use something like a [scope guard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189).

*(Untested pseudocode, but hope you get the idea.)*

```
template <typename TIterator>
class multiple_lock_guard
{
private:
    TIterator _begin, _end;

    multiple_lock_guard(TIterator begin, TIterator end)
        : _begin{begin}, _end{end}
    {
        for(auto it = _begin; it != _end; ++it)
        {
            it->_mutex.lock();
        }
    }

    ~multiple_lock_guard()
    {
        for(auto it = _begin; it != _end; ++it)
        {
            it->_mutex.unlock();
        }
    }
};
```

You can use it as follows:

```
void Container::desired_main_method()
{
    multiple_lock_guard mlg(std::begin(_vData), std::end(_vData));

    for(int i = 0; i < _vData.size(); i++)
    {
        this->processing(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < _vData.size(); i++)
    {
        this->post_processing(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why write your own? Standard library has a lot of features (surrounding `std::lock` with `defer_lock_t`). Boost makes it even more powerful with iterator-range interface (see my answer). Note it will be a lot more robust, because your implementation is naturally deadlock-prone

Comment: @sehe: Fair points - my answer aims to show the OP how to solve its "multiple lock guard" problem in a generic way that can be applied for similar issues and shows how to implement your own RAII wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
void Container::desired_main_method()
{
  std::vector<boost::mutex::scoped_lock> locks;

  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    locks.emplace_back(_vData.at(i)->_mutex);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    this->processing(i);
  }

  for (int i=0; i<_vData.size(); i++)
  {
    this->post_processing(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already use the free function extensions from Boost Thread to atomically lock a collection of deferred locks:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_range
- sadly, c++17 doesn't offer this overload http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d04c3f1f59cc8566)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct X {
    boost::mutex mutable mx;
};

void foo(std::vector<X> const& xs) {

    std::vector<boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> > locks;
    for (auto& x : xs) {
        locks.emplace_back(x.mx, boost::defer_lock);
    }

    boost::lock(locks.begin(), locks.end());

    // all locks held
}

int main() {
    std::vector<X> xs(10);
    foo(xs);
}
```